# Nepali Date-picker show on document.ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using a custom calendar datepicker from the following link

http://sajanmaharjan.com.np/nepali-datepicker/

This datepicker seems to be working fine but I am failing to display the date-picker by default when a page loads.

we can display the calendar of jquery with $('#id').datepicker('show'), however above datepicker
doesn't have any such functionality. it can only be accessed only when a user clicks on textbox.

I tried initializing datepicker with an Id of an element

`<div id="nepaliDate"></div>`

```
     $(function(){
          $('#nepaliDate').nepaliDatePicker();
     });
```

Above code doesn't display calendar on page load.

The only code that works is with input type="text" and when we click on the textbox

```
     <input type="text" id="nepaliDate"/>
     $(function(){
          $('#nepaliDate').nepaliDatePicker();
     });
```

Could any please help me in knowing how can I display the calendar on document.ready or window.load?

Thanks

Comment: Well the documentation does not show any method to show it by default. but maybe `$('#nepaliDate').nepaliDatePicker().trigger("click")` could work

Comment: Nope. I am getting an error that says : jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trigger')

Comment: This plugin dont need jQuery

Comment: could you please tell me what to do about it?